# Next.js 404: NOT FOUND

Tags: reactjs, vercel, next.js13

I have published my next app on Vercel and gpt 404: NOT FOUND error and it seems like Vercel can't see my pages in app folder. Can someone recognise what is the issue here ?

https://github.com/aberkayk/guclu-grup
https://guclu-grup-cztw-d5qlogpvk-aberkayk.vercel.app/

I have checked next docs but couldn't find something fixes the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the relevant details of your setup as well as your code in text.  You need to clarify how you tried to debug this issue.